# cmake setting for cuda&visual studio

Tags: cmake, cuda

How to set up custom CUDA directory for `enable_language(CUDA)`?

From cmake version 3.8~ ,I can use `enable_language(CUDA)` command.

In my custom cmake file, I set `CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR` same as cuda custom directory(not an default directory).

But when `enable_language(CUDA)`command is called, cmake default modules are trying to find CUDA in default directory(somewhere in c:\progrmafiles).

I don't want make my teammate install CUDA toolkit separately.

So i want to include all necessary component and tools for using CUDA in custom directory.

How can i make it done?

Target Environment Info

```
OS windows 7 x64 (only)

IDE visual studio 2013

cmake version 3.11.4

CUDA version 9.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I look at [`CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake) you can select a specific compiler for `enable_language(CUDA)` via:

1. The environment variable [`CUDACXX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CUDACXX.html) (for non-"Visual Studio" environments)

   ```
   > cmake -E env CUDACXX="<your CUDA path here>" cmake ..
   ```
2. Simply set global variable [`CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html)

   ```
   > cmake -D CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER:FILEPATH="<your CUDA path here>" ..
   ```

   or in your `CMakeLists.txt` before your `project()` or `enable_language()` 
   call

   ```
   if (NOT CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
       set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/<your CUDA relative path here>")
   endif()
   ```